# pi4j-maven Archetype support via Maven in Intelli Idea

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, pi4j

I want to write java code using the dependency [Pi4j](https://pi4j.com/) and using Intellij on Windows 10. The target platform is a Pi Zero W.

The [instructions](https://pi4j.com/getting-started/developing-on-a-remote-pc/) to develop on remote (Windows 10 in this case) PC say to add the [p4j-maven-archetype](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-maven-archetype) but don't explain how to use this maven tool within the maven included with Intellij.

I have tried to download the p4j-maven-archetype, extract it, then open Intellij and import p4j-maven-archetype as a project. Then from within Intellij I run the maven goal install so it can be used in other projects.

How would I now create a new project within Intellij using the p4j-maven-archetype that I installed?

Is there a way to package and run it remotely on the Pi from Intellij?

Comment: in IntelliJ IDEA navigate to "File > New Project > Maven ", tick the "From archetype" option, and choose the downloaded archetype using the "Add archetype" button: https://i.imgur.com/Lq4mqeS.png

Answer (score 1):

Since this is an archetype that you first need to install into your local Maven repository, follow the steps from corresponding [instructions](https://github.com/Pi4J/pi4j-maven-archetype#install-the-archetype-to-your-local-m2-repository) for the archetype project:

> Install the archetype to your local .m2 repository
> Unzip the archetype file in a folder

```
cd folder/raspimaven-archetype
mvn install
```

Then use project generation Maven command:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeCatalog=local
```

Or use IDE wizard to create the project from the locally installed archetype: New Project | Maven -> **Create from archetype**:

[image]